# codeigniter save any transactions

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and my sql DB in my system

I'm tried to find a solution to my problem is :
in update my record in database i want Keep the record before editing it In order to be presented in the end of year report and The calculations of the year are done correctly 
What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

when a database record is updated you cannot fetch the old record.
What you can do is to create another table and insert the record in there before editing it.

Comment: I tried the both above solutions but they are not efficient My Database Containing 100 table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table in your database, "table A" which is the table you are currently updating, create another table, "table B" that you will be saving the actual data you feel will be needed to do the yearly calculations. Do not forget to add a **year** column on "table B".

Comment: I tried the both above solutions but they are not efficient My Database Containing 100 table